# "Refused to load the image" in a Chrome App

Tags: dart, google-chrome-app, content-security-policy

I have this problem in dart

> Refused to load the image 'https://**.png' because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:
>   chrome-extension-resource:".

when try to set src in image element

```
ImageButtonInputElement button = new ImageButtonInputElement();
button.className="button_element";
button.src=el["imageUrl"]; //like "https://**.png"
```

whit this manifest.json

```
"content_security_policy":"img-src https://server.example.org"
```

Someone would know help me?

Thanks

Sorry for my bad English

**EDIT**

I have the same problem with

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="https://server.example.org/example.html"></iframe>
```

> Refused to frame
>   https://server.example.org/example.html
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "frame-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource:".

Comment: Do you have exact server name in your CSP string? I mean something like `"img-src https://server.example.org"`? Because CSP doc says the following: Generic wildcards such as https:, https://* and https://*.com are not allowed; subdomain wildcards such as https://*.example.com are allowed.

Comment: Yes, I used (https://**.png) as an example but in my code I used the full link.

Comment: Just to be clear, I mean CSP string, not image url you are trying to load. In your example there is `https://` without anything else, which is not allowed IMHO

Comment: Yes, I used code like "content_security_policy":"img-src https://server.example.org" . Sorry, edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution I have adopted in the end:

```
var imgRequest = new HttpRequest();
imgRequest.open('GET', url);
imgRequest.responseType = 'blob';
imgRequest.onReadyStateChange.listen((var request){
  if (imgRequest.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE &&
      imgRequest.status == 200) {
      FileReader reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onLoad.listen((fe) { 
        button.src = reader.result;
      });
      reader.readAsDataUrl(imgRequest.response); 
    }  

});

imgRequest.send();
```

Answer (score 2):

Apps [cannot override the CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy). That manifest key is only for extensions.

[See documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#external) for loading remote content for display.

Likewise, you have to use [`<webview>`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview) instead of iframes in a Chrome App.

Comment: Thank you! I try to answer with the solution I have adopted.