# Failed to load image because it's violating content security policy

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-app, content-security-policy

In chrome app I am trying to load images from  external link but getting error

> Refused to load the image
>   'unsafe:https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png' because it
>   violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src
>   'self' blob: filesystem: data: chrome-extension-resource:

I already added content_security_policy in manifest.json file

```
"content_security_policy": "img-src 'self' https://www.google.co.in/ blob: filesystem: data: chrome-extension-resource:;"
```

and

also explicitly added URL protocols to Angular's whitelist using a regular expression

```
.config(['$compileProvider',
    function ($compileProvider) {
        var currentImgSrcSanitizationWhitelist = $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist();
        var newImgSrcSanitizationWhiteList = currentImgSrcSanitizationWhitelist.toString().slice(0, -1)
        + '|chrome-extension:'
        + currentImgSrcSanitizationWhitelist.toString().slice(-1);

        console.log("Changing imgSrcSanitizationWhiteList from " + currentImgSrcSanitizationWhitelist + " to " + newImgSrcSanitizationWhiteList);
        $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(newImgSrcSanitizationWhiteList);
    }
        ]);
```

but still error is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** override [CSP for Chrome Apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy) (that key is only for extensions).

You will need to adapt your App to fetch then locally cache the images - you can't embed them directly. See Google's guide on [Referencing external resources](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#external).

Also, take another look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544033/refused-to-load-the-image-in-a-chrome-app?rq=1) - if you're getting `unsafe:` in your URLs you aren't doing it correctly.